# A Large Number of Similar Functions

Tags: python, database, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, data-conversion

There are two databases, **Db_A** and **Db_B**, each with their own data dictionary. Most of the data in my database, **Db_A**, will fit in some field or another of the target database **Db_B**. Many values from **Db_A** will require reformatting before being inserted into fields in **Db_B**, and some values to be inserted into **Db_B** will need to be derived from multiple fields in **Db_A**. Very few fields in **Db_A** will be transferable to **Db_B** without at least some processing. Some fields may require a lot of processing (especially those which are derived). Unfortunately the processing steps are not very consistent. Each field will essentially require its own unique conversion.

In other words, I have a large set of fields. Each field needs to be processed in a specific way. These fields may change and the way they need to be processed may change. What is the best way of implementing this system?

One way I've done this in the past was to have a central function which loops through each field, calling that fields function. I created one function per field and used a csv file to map fields to functions and to the parameters the functions need. That way if a new field is created, I can just update the csv file and write a method to handle its conversion. If the way a field is converted needs to be changed, I can just change the corresponding method.

Is this a good way of doing it? Any suggestions? I'm using Python.

Comment: A csv file is interesting for sharing data between applications, in your case, it could be also a python file with a dictionnary that match a field (key) to a function (value)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Good idea. Probably easier to read in a dictionary than parse the csv.